# Angular 7 - Stripping out inline CSS from html called by Ajax

Tags: angular

So learning angular/ionic at the moment and I have the following:

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="dashboardWrap" [innerHTML]="dashboardHTML"></div>
</ion-content>

loadDash(){

    console.log('loading dash');

    this.http.post(this.appService.getWPEndPoint('content/dashboard'),null,{}).subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      this.dashboardHTML = resp.data.html;
    });

  }
```

This is pulling HTML from a web server and also has css in  tags. The html is being applied to the div in question but it's stripping out the CSS styles; I need it to keep those styles as it's for dynamic content loading purposes.

How can I prevent angular stripping this out? it also seems to be stripping out ID tags from the html as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example `resp.data.html`?

Comment: You might also need to check out the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: I've seen the DomSanitizer recently, I'll have a look, it's not really easy to paste in the html from the JSON and angular is stripping it out so can't get it from the dom. I'll have a look into the Sanitizer

Comment: If Angular is stripping it out, it's because it's being sanitized. You probably also have a warning in the DevTools console that says something like "WARNING: Some of your content has been stripped from this request".

Answer (score 0):

Inject `DomSanitizer` into your component and then pass the response from the web service call to `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` and set your bound value to the result.

```
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

loadDash(){
  this.http.post(this.appService.getWPEndPoint('content/dashboard'),null {})
    .subscribe((resp) => {
      this.dashboardHTML = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(resp.data.html);
  });
}
```